# JQUERY + HEYGRADY transformation library

Tags: jquery, html, rotation, transform

I am trying to rotate and translate a div about a point and came across a library for transformation purposes.

https://github.com/heygrady/transform

It works very well, but when i try to do the following operations

- Rotate
- Translate by x and y
- Origin (0%, 50%)

It does not work as expected. If i translate alone it works fine but the origin is not applied.

If i rotate it with the above origin values it rotates about that point but translation is messed up.

When i apply translation and rotation together the div itself flies off to some undesired position(out of the screen).

I would like to know if it is possible to apply translation and rotation at the same time thus expecting the desired results.

And the div element has been positioned with absolute.

below is the code.

```
$("#mydiv").transform(
    {
        origin:['0%','50%'],
        rotate:angle+'deg',
        translate:[mouse.x+'px',mouse.y+'px']
    });
```

the variable names inside my code is for the purpose of understanding that it is applied dynamically. Or does this need to be done the matrix way?

Regards,

Ashok Srinivasan.